# How to convert Sql orderby clause with Case Statement into JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to convert `Sql` orderby clause with Case using `JOOQ`.and BillAmount is of `BigDecimal` datatype.

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN (BillAmount <= 0) 
THEN
 BillAmount 
ELSE
 BillNumber 
END
```

How to write the above line using `JOOQ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to directly translate your SQL clause to a corresponding jOOQ clause using the [`CASE` expression (as documented in the manual)](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/)

```
.orderBy(DSL.decode().when(BillAmount.le(0), BillAmount)
                     .otherwise(BillNumber))
```