# JOOQ Orderby with Case Statement

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Here is my issue..

```
SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery  = transRefundFee.selectQuery();
selectQuery.addSelect(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_NUMBER,AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT,AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.TOTAL_PAID );
selectQuery.addFrom(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL);
selectQuery.addConditions(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.FOLDER_RSN.eq(argFolderRSN));
```

I have to add the orderby with Case Statement how can we do this i checked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654784/how-to-convert-sql-orderby-clause-with-case-statement-into-jooq) but its not working in my case any other way I Added like this

```
selectQuery.addOrderBy( DSL.decode().when(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT.le(new BigDecimal(0)),AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT).then(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT) .otherwise(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_NUMBER));
```

But its saying `The method then(TableField<AccountBillRecord,BigDecimal>) is undefined for the type CaseConditionStep<BigDecimal>`

Same with below code

```
selectQueryFee.addOrderBy(DSL.decode().when(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT.le(new BigDecimal(0))
                    .then(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT)
                    .otherwise(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_NUMBER)));
```

> The method then(TableField) is undefined
>   for the type Condition

Comment: Have you had a look at the [`SelectQuery`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectQuery.html) Javadoc? What have you tried? Where / why did you fail?

Comment: Whoops. I noticed I had given a wrong answer in the [other question, which you've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19656354/521799)

Answer (score 2):

As of jOOQ 3.2, the `CASE` expression support does not implement a `when()` ... `then()` structure, i.e. there's no `then()` keyword. Instead, write:

```
DSL.decode()
   .when(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT.le(new BigDecimal(0)), 
         AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_AMOUNT)
   .otherwise(AccountBill.ACCOUNT_BILL.BILL_NUMBER)
```

There has been a pending feature request on the jOOQ roadmap to rectify this: [#615](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/615)

Comment: I have to do Casting here? The method otherwise(BigDecimal) in the type CaseConditionStep<BigDecimal> is not applicable for the arguments (TableField<AccountBillRecord,Integer>)

Comment: @subodh: The method signatures are : `when(Condition, T).otherwise(T)`. So `BILL_AMOUNT` and `BILL_NUMBER` have to be of the same type. Otherwise you'll have to cast, yes